# Ctrl-shift-tab keyboard shortcut broken when screen sharing Mac OS to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Using ubuntu 16.04 with Unity and VNC screen sharing enabled and remoting in from an OS X machine using built-in screen sharing app. The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> seems to behave as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. For instance in Chrome, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will move to the next tab instead of previous tab.